# Winforms label drawing over a button with custom drawing

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this little app that has a button and a label. The button has a custom OnPaint methods to make it look unique. The label currently does not. However the label seems to be drawing inside the button for no apparent reason. Look at this:

[image: The problem]

For clarities sake I've disabled rendering the fill rectangle since it mostly covers the problem. Here's my button's OnPaint code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Pen p = new Pen (Color.Black, 2);
        Rectangle fillRect = new Rectangle (e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 2, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 2);
        Brush b;
        if (MouseHovering)
        {
            b = new SolidBrush (Color.DarkSlateGray);
        } 
        else
        {
            b = new SolidBrush (Color.Gray);
        }
        //g.FillRectangle (b, fillRect);
        g.DrawRectangle (p, e.ClipRectangle);
        //g.DrawString (Text, new Font ("Arial", 8), new SolidBrush (Color.Black), new Point (4, 4));
    }
```

And here is the code that creates the label and button in the main form class:

```
label = new Label ();
label.Text = "Hello World";
label.Top = 15;
label.Left = 180;
label.AutoSize = true;
Controls.Add (label);
CButton b = new CButton ();
b.Text = "Click me for a new sentence";
b.AutoSize = true;
b.Top = 10; b.Left = 10;
Controls.Add (b);
```

The above is called in the constructor. And then when the button is pressed the label text is set like this:

```
label.Text = Specifier + " " + Verb + " a " + CommonNoun;
```

So what's happening here and how do I fix it? If you require any other code to understand the problem don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Try `g.Clear(BackColor)` at the top of your paint routine. Also don't use the clipping rectangle, just use `Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);`, and make sure you dispose of your GDI objects when you get to the end (`b.Dispose()`, `p.Dispose()`)

Comment: @Ron Beyer should post this as a solution.  So it can be accepted.

Comment: @tgolisch Done, was just busy before, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things missing. `g.Clear(BackColor);` will clear the contents of the buffer that the Graphics object is painting on.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.Clear(BackColor);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Pen p = new Pen (Color.Black, 2);
        Rectangle fillRect = new Rectangle (e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 2, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 2);
        Brush b;
        if (MouseHovering)
        {
            b = new SolidBrush (Color.DarkSlateGray);
        } 
        else
        {
            b = new SolidBrush (Color.Gray);
        }
        //g.FillRectangle (b, fillRect);
        g.DrawRectangle (p, e.ClipRectangle);
        //g.DrawString (Text, new Font ("Arial", 8), new SolidBrush (Color.Black), new Point (4, 4));
        b.Dispose();   //ADD THIS
        p.Dispose();   //ADD THIS TOO
    }
```

Also remember that its very important to dispose of any GDI resources that you are using. These might be .NET constructs, but they really are unmanaged objects in the background. Disposing them properly will prevent memory leaks and hard-to-understand crashes.

Also, you shouldn't be using the clip rectangle, use the actual bounds of the control.

The best option is to wrap them in using statements:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        Color fillColor = MouseHovering ? Color.DarkSlateGray : Color.Gray;

        using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(fillColor))
        {
            Rectangle fillRect = new Rectangle (0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

            g.DrawRectangle (p, e.ClipRectangle);
        }
    }
```

Using the `using` statement has the added benefit of if there is an exception inside the using, the objects will still be disposed correctly. The other option is to wrap them in a `try..catch..finally`, but unless you need to do something with the exception, this is a lot cleaner.